# Checking if all values for user_id IS NOT NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have dataset which looks like this:

```
UserID  AccountID   CloseDate
1        1000       14/3/2022
1        2000       16/3/2022
2        1000       NULL
2        2000       4/3/2022
2        3000       NULL
```

And I would like to check if within one user_id all of the close dates are not null. In other words if all accounts within user_id are closed. I was trying using MAX or MIN but it is not working as I expected, because it is simply avoiding NULL values. Is there any other function which can check it? Let's say that my output would be another column which will assign 1 when all CloseDates are not null and else 0.

Sample output:

```
UserID  AccountID   CloseDate   Check
1        1000       14/3/2022   1
1        2000       16/3/2022   1
2        1000       NULL        0
2        2000       4/3/2022    0
2        3000       NULL        0
```

Comment: What's the output that you want?

Comment: provide text instead of image,it helps to get faster guidance from community.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation to explicitly `COUNT` the rows where the column has the value `NULL`:

```sql
SELECT GroupedColumn,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN NullableColumn IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS NullCount
FROM dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY GroupedColumn;
```

If you want to just have a `1` or `0` just wrap the count in a `CASE` expression:

```sql
CASE COUNT(CASE WHEN NullableColumn IS NULL THEN 1 END) WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I expected :)

Comment: By the way, a slightly shorter but more confusing option is `COUNT(*) - COUNT(NullableColumn)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `FIRST_VALUE` condition window function

```
SELECT *,
       FIRST_VALUE(IIF(CloseDate IS NULL,0,1)) OVER(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY CloseDate )
FROM T
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=e589f38e885c9d04b1da01485a85543a)

Answer (score 1):

```
with dataset as (select 1 as UserId, 1000 as AccountID, '14/3/2022' as CloseDate 
                 union all select 1, 2000, '16/3/2022' 
                 union all select 2, 1000, NULL 
                 union all select 2, 2000, '4/3/2022' 
                 union all select 2, 3000, NULL)


select userid from dataset 
group by userid 
having sum(case when closedate is null then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select d.*, iif(chk>0, 0, 1) chk
from d
outer apply (
    select UserId, COUNT(*) CHK
    from d dd
    WHERE d.UserId = dd.UserId
    and dd.CloseDate IS NULL
    group by UserId
) C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "exists". e.g. :

```
select y.UserID, y.AccountID, y.CloseDate, 

-- [Check]: returns 0 if there is a row in the table for the 
-- UserID where CloseDate is null, else 1  
(case when exists(select * from YourTable y2 where y2.UserID = y.UserID
AND y2.CloseDate is null) then 0 else 1 end) as [Check] 

from YourTable y
```